# Fill temp table with zero values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table #results and i fill that table with some values, but if i don't have match it doesn't fill the table till the end for last 8 weeks

Here is my insert and merge code

```
INSERT INTO #Results (
            [PlayerId],
            [CalendarWeekID],
            [TotalDepositAmount],
            [TotalDepositCount],
            [TotalWithdrawalAmount],
            [TotalWithdrawalCount]
            )
        SELECT
            [PlayerId],
            [CalendarWeekID],
            SUM(Aggr.DepositAmount)     [Deposits],
            SUM(Aggr.DepositCount)      [DepositCount],
            SUM(Aggr.WithdrawalAmount)  [Withdrawals],                      
            SUM(Aggr.WithdrawalCount)   [WithdrawalCount]
       FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactPaymentAgr] Aggr
       JOIN WarehouseMgmt.DimTime DT on DT.Id = Aggr.TimeId
       WHERE (CalendarWeekId BETWEEN @CurrentWeek7 AND @CurrentWeek) AND [PlayerId] = @PlayerID
       GROUP BY [PlayerId],[CalendarWeekID]

    MERGE #Results AS Target
          USING(    SELECT 
                        [PlayerId],
                        [CalendarWeekID],
                        SUM(Aggr.FinancialBetAmount) [TotalBetAmount],
                        SUM(Aggr.FinancialBetCount)  [TotalBetCount]
                    FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactWalletAgr] Aggr
                    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL ON Aggr.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id] 
                    JOIN WarehouseMgmt.DimTime DT on DT.Id = Aggr.TimeId
                    WHERE (CalendarWeekId BETWEEN @CurrentWeek7 AND @CurrentWeek) AND [PlayerId] = @PlayerID
                    GROUP BY [PlayerId],[CalendarWeekID]) AS Source
          ON (Target.[PlayerId] = Source.[PlayerId])
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE SET  Target.[TotalBetAmount] = Source.[TotalBetAmount],
                            Target.[TotalBetCount] = Source.[TotalBetCount] ;
```

And current result for one player will be in this format

PlayerId Some amounts and counts CalendarWeekId CalendarWeek
1110,10,1,... 201553(week id)
1110,1000,23,...201547(weekId)

but what i want is to have for all last 8 weeks data in table, even it is 0
So the right format will be

1. 1110,10,1,... 201553(week id)
2. 1110,0,0,... 201552(week id)
3. 1110,0,0,... 201552(week id)
4. 1110,0,0,... 201551(week id)
5. 1110,0,0,... 201550(week id)
6. 1110,0,0,... 201549(week id)
7. 1110,0,0,... 201548(week id)
8. 1110,1000,23,...201547(weekId)

Missing rows should be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only including data for one player, so you can solve this using a `left join`.  The `insert` statement should look like:

```
INSERT INTO #Results ( . . . )
   SELECT . . .
   FROM WarehouseMgmt.DimTime DT LEFT JOIN
        WarehouseMgmt.FactPaymentAgr Aggr
        ON DT.Id = Aggr.TimeId AND [PlayerId] = @PlayerID
   WHERE (CalendarWeekId BETWEEN @CurrentWeek7 AND @CurrentWeek) 
   GROUP BY PlayerId, CalendarWeekID
```

Comment: Ok i rearrange the query but there is one problem, CANNOT INSERT NULL VALUES INTO PlayerId

Comment: This answer is a start.  You also need an isnull() function for every field you want defaulted to zero.

Comment: @user2171512 . . . When you create the temporary table, give the numeric columns a default value of zero.  That is probably the simplest solution.